# Split a JSON type data into different columns

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I am getting a value from a parameter as below:

```
{ "Line1":"Nav Place Road", "Line2":"Nyork City", "Line3":"USA 34576" }
```

I want it to be displayed as follows:

```
ColumnName  Value
---------------------------
Line1       Nav Place Road
Line2       Nyork City
Line3       USA 34576
```

How can I parse it without using JSON function?

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? We're here to *assist* not do it all.

Answer (score 2):

Before v2016 there is no native JSON support.

But your format can be translated to XML relatively easy...

```
DECLARE @YourJson NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'{ "Line1":"Nav Place Road", "Line2":"Nyork City", "Line3":"USA 34576" }';

SELECT x.value('@name','nvarchar(max)') AS TheName
      ,x.value('@value','nvarchar(max)') AS TheValue
FROM (VALUES(CAST(CONCAT('<x name=',REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@YourJson,'{',''),'}',''),':"',' value="'),', "','/> <x name="'),' />') AS XML))) A(Casted)
CROSS APPLY Casted.nodes('/x') B(x);
```

The idea in short:

We use simple string methods to transform your JSON to this:

```
<x name="Line1" value="Nav Place Road" />
<x name="Line2" value="Nyork City" />
<x name="Line3" value="USA 34576" />
```

This can be read using native XML support.

Attention: If your values might include commas, or if the blanks are not the same everywhere, this would need deeper thinking...

Answer (score 0):

This should be as simple as:

```
declare @js nvarchar(1000) = '{ "Line1":"Nav Place Road", "Line2":"Nyork City", "Line3":"USA 34576" }';

SELECT t.[Key] columnName, t.[Value] FROM OPENJSON(@js, '$') t;
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=01e856b35c3d6c340c438b1d5cbadd82)**:

```
columnName | Value         
:--------- | :-------------
Line1      | Nav Place Road
Line2      | Nyork City    
Line3      | USA 34576
```

Comment: GMB I think he wants to do it in SQL Server 2012. This functionality is only available in 2017 and above.

Comment: I am using SQL Server 2012. Getting the error "Invalid Object JSON"